# pattern() vs toString() in Pattern class

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

What is the difference between the `pattern()` method and the `toString()` method in the `Pattern` class?

The doc says:

```
public String pattern()
```

> Returns the regular expression from which this pattern was compiled.

```
public String toString()
```

> Returns the string representation of this pattern. This is the regular expression from which this pattern was compiled.

Even their implementation returns the same result:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+\\.?");
    String s = p.pattern();
    String d = p.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(d);
  }
}
```

I see no difference, so why are there two methods? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because each class has a `toString()` method which was inherited from `Object`. The `toString()` method is supposed to return a string which represents the object the best way it can, if it is even possible to create some kind of string representation.
The name `toString()` is pretty vague, so they added a method `pattern()` which is more straightforward.

And because they wanted `toString()` to return something clever they used the pattern of the regex, which is a good string representation for the `Pattern` class.

Comment: @martijin: thats it?? ... i dnt no why but i feel cheated!! thnx anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` method is in each class(extends from class `Object`). There is an example. `System.out.print(Object o);` can print some information about `Object`. Actually this will be the same: `System.out.print(o.toString())`. So you have simple way to see what the Object you have. Try:

```
Object someUnknownObject = new JButton();
System.out.println(someUnknownObject);

// output
javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5...
```

As you see you can see information about this object, even if you don't know this is a button at all.

Also `String` is an `Object` so there is one weird example:

```
String str = "hello";
String toStr = str.toString();

System.out.println(str.toString().toString().toString()...);
```

This is unuseful, but `all classes have this method`. So "my string" and "my string".toString() is the same